# pagination with codeigniter not generating values

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have been trying to get this done, I want a pagination in my app.  what i have now can only count the table rows. but when i click on the link to next batch of data, i receive a error 404.

Here is the code below. 
This is my Controller

```
public function index($page='dboard', $offset=0){
        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'manager/cplfc/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('users','attendance');
        $config['per_page'] = 1;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 1;
        $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'pagination');

        // Init Pagination
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);


     $data['users'] = $this->ManagerModel->get_users(FALSE, $config['per_page'], $offset);

    if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/controls/manager/'.$page.'.php')){show_404();}
    $data['title']=ucfirst($page);
    $this->load->view('controls/manager/header');
    $this->load->view('controls/manager/'.$page,$data);
    $this->load->view('controls/manager/footer');
}
```

and this is the Model

```
public function get_users($id = FALSE, $limit = FALSE, $offset = FALSE){
    if($limit){
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        }
    if($id === FALSE){
        $this ->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result_array();
        }
    }
```

And this is my view

```
<div class="pagination pagination-centered">
                            <ul><li><?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?></li></ul>
                        </div>
```

What can i do to make it work? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed was to set the URL Segment to "4" because the URL

```
$config = array();
$offset = $this->uri->segment(4);
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'manager/cplfc/';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('users','attendance');
$config['per_page'] = 1;
$config['uri_segment'] = 1;
$config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'pagination');
```

Answer (score 0):

The pagination function automatically determines which segment of your URI contains the page number. If you need something different you can specify it and it should be normally `$config['uri_segment'] = 3;`

Comment: thanks for your reply. But its still showing 404 not found.

Comment: Show me the url!

Comment: thanks alot. it was my url that wasn't correct. I still have one more question. How can i sort data without having to refresh the page

Comment: in my code, i have a select object. I want it that in an "OnChange" even, the table values should change respectively

Comment: Do you mean you wanna make ajax pagination with sort option? .. easy on click on col header send a request with limit and offset but toggle order of it .. you can send it via form data or change pagination type to accept uri string and pass it as a get request .. i know its easier said than done but i hope you got the idea .. or if you prefer use datatables

Comment: currently, each time i search for related data, the page reloads. I want it in a way that it shouldn't reload the page when i search for related data. I know it can be achieved with AJAX. But my problem is how to do it.

Comment: Aha i got where you stuck into, i'm not sure i can write a full answer here, and i'm afraid to add another answer unrelated to the question but anyways.
in you pagination configs give an id or a class to the ul like this `$config['full_tag_open'] = '<nav aria-label="Page navigation example"><ul class="pagination pagination-sm justify-content-center">';` then in your js it is as easy as this `on('click', '.pagination li a', function (event)` and `event.preventDefault();`  then do your magic